# Union of domain of semidifferentials

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Please let me post a question although this is possibly known already because I did not find the statement.

Let $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
Let denote by $D^+ f$ and $D^- f$ the superdifferential and the subdifferential of $f$, respectively.
Also let define their domain as 
$$
\mathcal{D}^{\pm}f:=\{x\in(0,1) \mid D^{\pm}f(x)\neq\emptyset\}.
$$
Then does that $\mathcal{D}^+ f\cup\mathcal{D}^- f=(0,1)$ hold?

I have checked that several fundamental functions satisfy it, but I could not proof generally or find counterexamples.

Thank you in advance.

---

I use the following definition of semidifferential:
$$
D^+ f(x):=\{\phi'(x)\in\mathbb{R} \mid \text{$f-\phi$ attains a (local) maximum at $x$ for $\phi\in C^{1}(0,1)$}\}
$$
and
$$
D^- f(x):=\{\phi'(x)\in\mathbb{R} \mid \text{$f-\phi$ attains a (local) minimum at $x$ for $\phi\in C^1(0,1)$}\}.
$$

Comment: For general it's necessary to check, but if $f$ is smooth in $(0,1)$, then $\mathcal{D}^+ f=\mathcal{D}^- f=(0,1)$ since $D^+ f=D^-f=\{f'\}$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. But, according to Lemma 2.5 in https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/hj.pdf for example, I think my assertion is true.

Comment: Those notes use a different definition of the super and subdifferential to the one I was thinking of (and the one that, for example, is given in Wikipedia). Perhaps it is worth giving the definitions you are working with in your question.

Comment: I see. Thank you for advising. I write right now.

Comment: In your definitions, what is $\phi$?

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo. I modified the definition.